# Where does this name come from? root@<hostname>

Tags: linux, centos, centos-6

When I putty into my CentOS 6 server I am shown `root@` `DemandStream Development`

This was a copied and repurposed Linux VM from one of our development environments. How do I change this name? It seems to be an alias somewhere?

When I get the hostname:

```
hostname -s
```

I get:

```
28004-2-2734499
```

I checked `/etc/sysconfig/network` and do not find the DemandStream Development name there. Also it is not in /etc/hosts

Reference on [how to change CentOS hostnames](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/centos-hostname-change) from RackSpace.

Comment: Do you mean that "root@DemandStream Development" is showing on the shell prompt? While usually the hostname is used after the `@` in the prompt, it can be customized. See http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/CustomizeBash

Answer (score 1):

[image: Screenshot of use. Search UUID: zrGmQL%W&dpMiTatcDhbQ1vcO6Ina1dey9mvp%VoOtrhSbQ2mXEbd1a-wnfc]

After updating the hostname your current instance won't be updated. Use "su root" or
logout and login. Then Bash should display your new hostname.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your hostname in `/etc/hostname` and in `/etc/hosts`

If you want to find the file that contains that string `28004-2-2734499` you may want to to a grep search like this:

```
sudo grep -rnw '/etc/' -e "28004-2-2734499"
```

Other ways to change host like this; leave out the brackets:
    sudo hostname [newhostname]

Or:

```
sudo sysctl kernel.hostname=[your_new_hostname]
```

Otherwise take a look at [this other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12829/how-to-change-the-hostname-of-a-linux-machine-using-terminal) and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

When I adjust hostnames on machines that already have a hostname set, I do the following. First, I check what the hostname is set to using plain `hostname` like this:

```
hostname
```

Then after checking what the current hostname is set to, I change it to something new like this; of course change `[new_hostname]` to match your new hostname:

```
sudo hostname [new_hostname]
```

On Debian/Ubuntu-based systems I then edit `/etc/hostname` to set the new hostname:

```
sudo nano /etc/hostname
```

That file should simply contain the hostname as you wish it to be; nothing more or less. Then I run the `init.d` script to make that change active; note this is not always needed on all Debian/Ubuntu-based systems:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/hostname.sh start
```

On RedHat/CentOS-based systems, the file `/etc/sysconfig/network` might need to be adjusted. When you open it it might have entries like this:

```
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME="my_hostname"
GATEWAY="192.168.0.1"
GATEWAYDEV="eth0"
FORWARD_IPV4="yes"
```

Note this is an example; just pay attention to what the value of `HOSTNAME` is and change it to match the hostname value you want set.

Finally, regardless of Unix flavor, checking and setting the kernel hostname. Running this command will show you what the current kernel hostname setting is:

```
sysctl kernel.hostname
```

The output would be something like this:

```
kernel.hostname = my_hostname
```

Now to change that, just run this command; of course change `new_hostname` to match whatever new hostname you want it to be set to:

```
sudo sysctl kernel.hostname=new_hostname
```

After all that is done, you might have to change your `/etc/hosts` file to match the new hostname settings:

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

But when all of that is done, just logout and then log back into the server. The new hostname should now be set.